# TYPO3 Errors in setup file

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm creating a small website after working with the extension builder. I had to create a page based on categories. So while checking my php files I have errors in my TypoScript file. I have attached the files and errors.
I'm finding some problem in TYPO3 getting several errors in setup.ts file.

My TypoScript

```
plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_information {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_information.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_information.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_information.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_information.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    features {
        # if set to 1, the enable fields are ignored in BE context
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
        # Should be on by default, but can be disabled if all action in the plugin are uncached
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 1
    }
}
```

```
plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_management {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_management.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_management.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_management.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_management.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    features {
        # if set to 1, the enable fields are ignored in BE context
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
        # Should be on by default, but can be disabled if all action in the plugin are uncached
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 1
    }
}
```

```
 plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_administration {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_administration.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_administration.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:oldglod_application/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_administration.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_oldglodapplication_administration.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    features {
        # if set to 1, the enable fields are ignored in BE context
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
        # Should be on by default, but can be disabled if all action in the plugin are uncached
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 1
    }
}
```

These are the errors and as I feel everything is fine.

```
Error:(1, 42) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(2, 10) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(3, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(3, 34) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(4, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(4, 39) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(5, 25) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(5, 33) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(6, 25) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(6, 38) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(7, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(7, 32) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(8, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(8, 37) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(10, 17) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(11, 30) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(12, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(14, 14) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(15, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(16, 9) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(16, 14) TS1005:'(' expected.
Error:(16, 18) TS1005:')' expected.
Error:(16, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(16, 28) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(16, 35) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(16, 42) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(16, 46) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(16, 60) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 9) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(18, 18) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 27) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 34) TS1128:Declaration or statement expected.
Error:(18, 40) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 44) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 47) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 56) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 59) TS1005:'(' expected.
Error:(18, 63) TS1005:')' expected.
Error:(18, 77) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 84) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(18, 88) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(21, 9) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(22, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(26, 41) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(27, 10) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(28, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(28, 34) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(29, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(29, 39) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(30, 25) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(30, 33) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(31, 25) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(31, 38) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(32, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(32, 32) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(33, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(33, 37) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(35, 17) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(36, 30) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(37, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(39, 14) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(40, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(41, 9) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(41, 14) TS1005:'(' expected.
Error:(41, 18) TS1005:')' expected.
Error:(41, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(41, 28) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(41, 35) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(41, 42) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(41, 46) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(41, 60) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 9) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(43, 18) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 27) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 34) TS1128:Declaration or statement expected.
Error:(43, 40) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 44) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 47) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 56) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 59) TS1005:'(' expected.
Error:(43, 63) TS1005:')' expected.
Error:(43, 77) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 84) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(43, 88) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(46, 9) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(47, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(51, 45) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(52, 10) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(53, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(53, 34) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(54, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(54, 39) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(55, 25) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(55, 33) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(56, 25) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(56, 38) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(57, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(57, 32) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(58, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(58, 37) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(60, 17) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(61, 30) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(62, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(64, 14) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(65, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(66, 9) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(66, 14) TS1005:'(' expected.
Error:(66, 18) TS1005:')' expected.
Error:(66, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(66, 28) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(66, 35) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(66, 42) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(66, 46) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(66, 60) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 9) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(68, 18) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 24) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 27) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 34) TS1128:Declaration or statement expected.
Error:(68, 40) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 44) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 47) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 56) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 59) TS1005:'(' expected.
Error:(68, 63) TS1005:')' expected.
Error:(68, 77) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 84) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(68, 88) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(71, 9) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(72, 5) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(76, 1) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(76, 9) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(76, 17) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(76, 21) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(76, 26) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(76, 49) TS1005:';' expected.
Error:(78, 28) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(79, 15) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(79, 21) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(79, 22) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(79, 29) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(80, 14) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(80, 17) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(80, 25) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(80, 30) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(83, 1) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(83, 21) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(84, 15) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(84, 21) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(84, 22) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(84, 29) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(85, 14) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(85, 17) TS1127:Invalid character.
Error:(85, 25) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(85, 30) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(88, 25) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(88, 31) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(89, 11) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(89, 20) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(89, 29) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(90, 11) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(90, 19) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(90, 22) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(90, 24) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(93, 25) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(93, 31) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(93, 34) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(94, 9) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(94, 16) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(94, 21) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(97, 25) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(97, 31) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(97, 34) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(98, 13) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(98, 19) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(98, 23) TS1005:':' expected.
Error:(101, 32) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(102, 14) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(105, 29) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(106, 16) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(1, 1) TS2552:Cannot find name 'plugin'. Did you mean 'Plugin'?
Error:(2, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'view'.
Error:(3, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templateRootPaths'.
Error:(3, 26) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(3, 31) TS2552:Cannot find name 'EXT'. Did you mean 'Text'?
Error:(3, 35) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(3, 55) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(3, 65) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(3, 73) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Templates'.
Error:(4, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templateRootPaths'.
Error:(4, 26) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(5, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'partialRootPaths'.
Error:(5, 25) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(5, 30) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(5, 34) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(5, 54) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(5, 64) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(5, 72) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Partials'.
Error:(6, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'partialRootPaths'.
Error:(6, 25) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(7, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'layoutRootPaths'.
Error:(7, 24) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(7, 29) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(7, 33) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(7, 53) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(7, 63) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(7, 71) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Layouts'.
Error:(8, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'layoutRootPaths'.
Error:(8, 24) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(10, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'persistence'.
Error:(11, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'storagePid'.
Error:(12, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'recursive'.
Error:(14, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'features'.
Error:(15, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'skipDefaultArguments'.
Error:(16, 14) TS2304:Cannot find name 'set'.
Error:(16, 18) TS2304:Cannot find name 'to'.
Error:(16, 21) TS2695:Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
Error:(16, 24) TS2304:Cannot find name 'the'.
Error:(16, 28) TS2304:Cannot find name 'enable'.
Error:(16, 35) TS2304:Cannot find name 'fields'.
Error:(16, 42) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(16, 46) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ignored'.
Error:(16, 57) TS2304:Cannot find name 'BE'.
Error:(16, 60) TS2304:Cannot find name 'context'.
Error:(17, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe'.
Error:(18, 11) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Should'.
Error:(18, 18) TS2304:Cannot find name 'be'.
Error:(18, 21) TS2304:Cannot find name 'on'.
Error:(18, 24) TS2304:Cannot find name 'by'.
Error:(18, 36) TS2304:Cannot find name 'but'.
Error:(18, 40) TS2304:Cannot find name 'can'.
Error:(18, 44) TS2304:Cannot find name 'be'.
Error:(18, 47) TS2304:Cannot find name 'disabled'.
Error:(18, 59) TS2304:Cannot find name 'all'.
Error:(18, 63) TS2304:Cannot find name 'action'.
Error:(18, 73) TS2304:Cannot find name 'the'.
Error:(18, 77) TS2304:Cannot find name 'plugin'.
Error:(18, 84) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(18, 88) TS2304:Cannot find name 'uncached'.
Error:(19, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments'.
Error:(21, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'mvc'.
Error:(22, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved'.
Error:(26, 1) TS2304:Cannot find name 'plugin'.
Error:(27, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'view'.
Error:(28, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templateRootPaths'.
Error:(28, 26) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(28, 31) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(28, 35) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(28, 55) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(28, 65) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(28, 73) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Templates'.
Error:(29, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templateRootPaths'.
Error:(29, 26) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(30, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'partialRootPaths'.
Error:(30, 25) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(30, 30) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(30, 34) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(30, 54) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(30, 64) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(30, 72) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Partials'.
Error:(31, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'partialRootPaths'.
Error:(31, 25) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(32, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'layoutRootPaths'.
Error:(32, 24) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(32, 29) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(32, 33) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(32, 53) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(32, 63) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(32, 71) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Layouts'.
Error:(33, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'layoutRootPaths'.
Error:(33, 24) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(35, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'persistence'.
Error:(36, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'storagePid'.
Error:(37, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'recursive'.
Error:(39, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'features'.
Error:(40, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'skipDefaultArguments'.
Error:(41, 14) TS2304:Cannot find name 'set'.
Error:(41, 18) TS2304:Cannot find name 'to'.
Error:(41, 21) TS2695:Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
Error:(41, 24) TS2304:Cannot find name 'the'.
Error:(41, 28) TS2304:Cannot find name 'enable'.
Error:(41, 35) TS2304:Cannot find name 'fields'.
Error:(41, 42) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(41, 46) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ignored'.
Error:(41, 57) TS2304:Cannot find name 'BE'.
Error:(41, 60) TS2304:Cannot find name 'context'.
Error:(42, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe'.
Error:(43, 11) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Should'.
Error:(43, 18) TS2304:Cannot find name 'be'.
Error:(43, 21) TS2304:Cannot find name 'on'.
Error:(43, 24) TS2304:Cannot find name 'by'.
Error:(43, 36) TS2304:Cannot find name 'but'.
Error:(43, 40) TS2304:Cannot find name 'can'.
Error:(43, 44) TS2304:Cannot find name 'be'.
Error:(43, 47) TS2304:Cannot find name 'disabled'.
Error:(43, 59) TS2304:Cannot find name 'all'.
Error:(43, 63) TS2304:Cannot find name 'action'.
Error:(43, 73) TS2304:Cannot find name 'the'.
Error:(43, 77) TS2304:Cannot find name 'plugin'.
Error:(43, 84) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(43, 88) TS2304:Cannot find name 'uncached'.
Error:(44, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments'.
Error:(46, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'mvc'.
Error:(47, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved'.
Error:(51, 1) TS2304:Cannot find name 'plugin'.
Error:(52, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'view'.
Error:(53, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templateRootPaths'.
Error:(53, 26) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(53, 31) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(53, 35) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(53, 55) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(53, 65) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(53, 73) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Templates'.
Error:(54, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templateRootPaths'.
Error:(54, 26) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(55, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'partialRootPaths'.
Error:(55, 25) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(55, 30) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(55, 34) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(55, 54) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(55, 64) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(55, 72) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Partials'.
Error:(56, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'partialRootPaths'.
Error:(56, 25) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(57, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'layoutRootPaths'.
Error:(57, 24) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(57, 29) TS2304:Cannot find name 'EXT'.
Error:(57, 33) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod_application'.
Error:(57, 53) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Resources'.
Error:(57, 63) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Private'.
Error:(57, 71) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Layouts'.
Error:(58, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'layoutRootPaths'.
Error:(58, 24) TS2364:The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
Error:(60, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'persistence'.
Error:(61, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'storagePid'.
Error:(62, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'recursive'.
Error:(64, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'features'.
Error:(65, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'skipDefaultArguments'.
Error:(66, 14) TS2304:Cannot find name 'set'.
Error:(66, 18) TS2304:Cannot find name 'to'.
Error:(66, 21) TS2695:Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
Error:(66, 24) TS2304:Cannot find name 'the'.
Error:(66, 28) TS2304:Cannot find name 'enable'.
Error:(66, 35) TS2304:Cannot find name 'fields'.
Error:(66, 42) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(66, 46) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ignored'.
Error:(66, 57) TS2304:Cannot find name 'BE'.
Error:(66, 60) TS2304:Cannot find name 'context'.
Error:(67, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe'.
Error:(68, 11) TS2304:Cannot find name 'Should'.
Error:(68, 18) TS2304:Cannot find name 'be'.
Error:(68, 21) TS2304:Cannot find name 'on'.
Error:(68, 24) TS2304:Cannot find name 'by'.
Error:(68, 36) TS2304:Cannot find name 'but'.
Error:(68, 40) TS2304:Cannot find name 'can'.
Error:(68, 44) TS2304:Cannot find name 'be'.
Error:(68, 47) TS2304:Cannot find name 'disabled'.
Error:(68, 59) TS2304:Cannot find name 'all'.
Error:(68, 63) TS2304:Cannot find name 'action'.
Error:(68, 73) TS2304:Cannot find name 'the'.
Error:(68, 77) TS2304:Cannot find name 'plugin'.
Error:(68, 84) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(68, 88) TS2304:Cannot find name 'uncached'.
Error:(69, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments'.
Error:(71, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'mvc'.
Error:(72, 6) TS2304:Cannot find name 'callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved'.
Error:(76, 3) TS2304:Cannot find name 'these'.
Error:(76, 9) TS2304:Cannot find name 'classes'.
Error:(76, 17) TS2304:Cannot find name 'are'.
Error:(76, 21) TS2304:Cannot find name 'only'.
Error:(76, 26) TS2304:Cannot find name 'used'.
Error:(76, 34) TS2304:Cannot find name 'auto'.
Error:(76, 34) TS2361:The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.
Error:(76, 39) TS2304:Cannot find name 'generated'.
Error:(76, 49) TS2304:Cannot find name 'templates'.
Error:(77, 1) TS2304:Cannot find name 'plugin'.
Error:(78, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'textarea'.
Error:(78, 17) TS2304:Cannot find name 'form'.
Error:(78, 22) TS2304:Cannot find name 'error'.
Error:(79, 16) TS2304:Cannot find name 'color'.
Error:(80, 25) TS2304:Cannot find name 'solid'.
Error:(83, 1) TS2304:Cannot find name 'input'.
Error:(83, 10) TS2304:Cannot find name 'form'.
Error:(83, 15) TS2304:Cannot find name 'error'.
Error:(84, 16) TS2304:Cannot find name 'color'.
Error:(85, 25) TS2304:Cannot find name 'solid'.
Error:(88, 2) TS2339:Property 'tx' does not exist on type '{ background: number; FF9F9F: any; border: number; px: any; FF0000: any; }'.
Error:(88, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod'.
Error:(88, 13) TS2304:Cannot find name 'application'.
Error:(88, 25) TS2304:Cannot find name 'table'.
Error:(89, 12) TS2304:Cannot find name 'collapse'.
Error:(90, 12) TS2304:Cannot find name 'spacing'.
Error:(90, 22) TS2304:Cannot find name 'px'.
Error:(93, 2) TS2339:Property 'tx' does not exist on type '{ border: number; separate: any; 10: any; }'.
Error:(93, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod'.
Error:(93, 13) TS2304:Cannot find name 'application'.
Error:(93, 25) TS2304:Cannot find name 'table'.
Error:(93, 31) TS2304:Cannot find name 'th'.
Error:(94, 10) TS2304:Cannot find name 'weight'.
Error:(97, 2) TS2339:Property 'tx' does not exist on type '{ font: number; bold: any; }'.
Error:(97, 5) TS2304:Cannot find name 'oldglod'.
Error:(97, 13) TS2304:Cannot find name 'application'.
Error:(97, 25) TS2304:Cannot find name 'table'.
Error:(97, 31) TS2304:Cannot find name 'td'.
Error:(98, 14) TS2304:Cannot find name 'align'.
Error:(101, 2) TS2339:Property 'typo3' does not exist on type '{ vertical: number; top: any; }'.
Error:(101, 8) TS2304:Cannot find name 'messages'.
Error:(101, 26) TS2304:Cannot find name 'error'.
Error:(102, 11) TS2304:Cannot find name 'red'.
Error:(105, 2) TS2339:Property 'typo3' does not exist on type '{ color: any; }'.
Error:(105, 8) TS2304:Cannot find name 'messages'.
Error:(105, 26) TS2304:Cannot find name 'ok'.
Error:(106, 11) TS2304:Cannot find name 'green'.
Warning:Cannot find parent tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Question moved to editing. Reviewing finished. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: From current code you posted its not clear where your scripts is... unless I scroll lengthy down. Please split it in two parts with code on top followed by error code in second code block, etc..

Comment: That looks as if you are using ".ts" as file ending for the TypoScript file whereas your IDE tries to interpret that as TypeScript. Try configuring your IDE to not interpret the setup.ts file as TypeScript and you should be fine.

Comment: @Susi can u please tell me how to do that

Comment: please provide the information which IDE you use. There might be a plugin for syntax highlightning of typoscript. Otherwise you only can remove the association `.ts`<->`typescript` and show .ts files as plain text files. Anyway a clean display of your typoscript errors can be found in the BE module web -> "Templates" in the "Template Analyzer".